# How to find the indices of the n largest numbers in an array that aren't 100 in Python

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I am trying to find the indices of an array of the n largest numbers from largest to smallest that aren't 100 in Python. I have found several different ways to find the top n maximum numbers from an array, and ways to exclude the values that are equal to 100, but not one that preserves the indices as well. This is what the array looks like:

```
array([ 10,  10,  11,  11,  10,  10,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  13,  14,
        14,  15, 100,  15,  12,  13,  11,  10,  12,  14,  14, 100, 100,
       100,  12,  13,  10,  10,  11,  13, 100, 100,  13,  14,  13,  12,
        10,  10,  11,  10, 100, 100, 100,  12,  13,  12,  13,  10,  10,
        10,  15, 100,  14,  14,  11,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  15,
        14,  10,  10,  10,  11,  10,  10,  10,  12,  11,  11,  10,  10,
        10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,
        10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10])
```

For an n of 10, I want an output like this:
array([14, 16, 63, 64, 12, 13, 22, 23, 55, 56])

I am preferably looking for one-liners if possible/an efficient way to perform this without using a traditional if/elif sorter. Let me know if the wording is confusing or if this problem has already been solved.

Comment: Waht have you tried? What about equal values? Please provide your attempt and explain what doesn't work in it (error/ouput vs expected output), otherwise this would look like "do my homewoerk for me", which we won't do.

Comment: My apologies, I wasn't aware that I should've documented all my attempts. I was actually able to solve this issue momentarily after posting this! Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 3):

First, sort the list but keep track of the original indices. In my solution below, I'm using tuples.

Then, go backward on the sorted list, and if the value is not **valueToIgnore**, then append the indice to *res* until *res* has a length of **n**.

```
n = 10
valueToIgnore = 100
array = [ 10,  10,  11,  11,  10,  10,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  13,  14,
        14,  15, 100,  15,  12,  13,  11,  10,  12,  14,  14, 100, 100,
       100,  12,  13,  10,  10,  11,  13, 100, 100,  13,  14,  13,  12,
        10,  10,  11,  10, 100, 100, 100,  12,  13,  12,  13,  10,  10,
        10,  15, 100,  14,  14,  11,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  15,
        14,  10,  10,  10,  11,  10,  10,  10,  12,  11,  11,  10,  10,
        10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,
        10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10]

array = [(i, val) for i,val in enumerate(array)]
array.sort(key= lambda x: x[1])

res = []
for i in range(len(array)-1, -1, -1):
    if len(res) == n: break

    if array[i][1] != valueToIgnore:
        res.append(array[i][0])

print(sorted(res))
# This will print [14, 16, 23, 36, 53, 55, 56, 63, 64, 65]
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do using numpy's [argsort](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) method which gives index sorted according to values in ascending order  and [where](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) method for coverting all the 100s to NaNs.

```
a = np.array([ 10,  10,  11,  11,  10,  10,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  13,  14,
    14,  15, 100,  15,  12,  13,  11,  10,  12,  14,  14, 100, 100,
   100,  12,  13,  10,  10,  11,  13, 100, 100,  13,  14,  13,  12,
    10,  10,  11,  10, 100, 100, 100,  12,  13,  12,  13,  10,  10,
    10,  15, 100,  14,  14,  11,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  15,
    14,  10,  10,  10,  11,  10,  10,  10,  12,  11,  11,  10,  10,
    10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,
    10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10])

n=3

nan_100 = np.where(a==100,np.NaN,a)

nan_count = sum(np.isnan(nan_100))

print(nan_100.argsort()[-1*n-nan_count:-1*nan_count][::-1])
```

Here, nan_100 variable will have array where 100s are converted to nan. I have counted the values of nan as argsort will move all the nan index to the end.

output:

```
array([64, 53, 16])
```

Answer (score 1):

Suppose array **a** has your data as follows. You can find **the indexes of top n largest values** as below:

```
import numpy as np

a=np.array([ 10,  10,  11,  11,  10,  10,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  13,  14,
        14,  15, 100,  15,  12,  13,  11,  10,  12,  14,  14, 100, 100,
       100,  12,  13,  10,  10,  11,  13, 100, 100,  13,  14,  13,  12,
        10,  10,  11,  10, 100, 100, 100,  12,  13,  12,  13,  10,  10,
        10,  15, 100,  14,  14,  11,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  15,
        14,  10,  10,  10,  11,  10,  10,  10,  12,  11,  11,  10,  10,
        10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,
        10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10])

aindexes=list(np.arange(0,a.shape[0])) # indexes of elements in a [0 1 2 ... 99]

sorted_a,sorteda_indexes=(list(t) for t in zip(*sorted(zip(a, aindexes),reverse=True))) #sort a in decending order and keep record of original indexes

n=10
topn_indx=sorteda_indexes[0:n] # select top n indexes
print("Top n largest values' indexes:",topn_indx)
```

It will print top 10 indexes as:

```
Top n largest values' indexes: [54, 45, 44, 43, 34, 33, 26, 25, 24, 15]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for opening this question, I was actually able to solve it using argsort:

```
array = [ 10,  10,  11,  11,  10,  10,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  13,  14,
          14,  15, 100,  15,  12,  13,  11,  10,  12,  14,  14, 100, 100,
         100,  12,  13,  10,  10,  11,  13, 100, 100,  13,  14,  13,  12,
          10,  10,  11,  10, 100, 100, 100,  12,  13,  12,  13,  10,  10,
          10,  15, 100,  14,  14,  11,  12,  12,  10,  10,  10,  15,  15,
          14,  10,  10,  10,  11,  10,  10,  10,  12,  11,  11,  10,  10,
          10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,
          10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10,  10]
n = 10
NumOf100s = np.count_nonzero(array == 100)
NotIncluding100s = array.argsort()[::-1][NumOf100s:NumOf100s+n]
print(NotIncluding100s)
array([64, 16, 14, 63, 53, 65, 56, 22, 13, 23])
```